# Redirecting exe generated cmd prompt data to text file

Tags: python, redirect, cmd

I have prepared an exe file using IEXPRESS on Windows 7 to run a Python script in cmd which copies some data to a product through ftp.

When the exe file is run, the command prompt opens and displays text describing the process. This works fine. But now I want to redirect all the cmd data to a text file.

Example: I run a file "se.exe". It opens cmd and displays "This is stackoverflow.com.", and closes. I want this text to be redirected to a text file.

Is there any way I can do this without having to modify the Python script?

Any suggestions would be appreciable.

```
import os
import sys
import string
import time
from ftplib import FTP
import filecmp

#Check for Ethernet connection
try:
     ftp = FTP('192.168.2.10','FACTORY','Factory','\0',3)
except:
     print 'Communication cannot be established...'
     print 'Check Ethernet connection or IP address and retry.'
     os.system('pause')
     sys.exit()

ftp.close();
time.sleep(3)
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run exe file from `cmd` like this:

```
se.exe 2 > log.txt
```

`log.txt` will contain the output of the program, including handle 2 (that is, STDERR) ([link for details](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb490982.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Northcat. Unfortunately, it did not work. The exe is placed on my desktop, and when I run it from the cmd the way you have mentioned, I am getting "Command line option syntax error. Type Command/ ? for Help."

If I remove the spaces between 2 and >, the exe runs, displays the text in command prompt, generates the text file, BUT the text file is empty.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Just thought to explain the requirement again: The exe I am running from cmd opens a new cmd and I want to copy the data from this new cmd to a text file.

Comment: It's very strange. It should works. Are you pass some options when you run se.exe?

Comment: No, I am not sending any additional parameters. I am using "cd" in cmd to go to the directory in which exe is present and then running it as you have mentioned. The text file created is empty.

Comment: You get empty file because `2> log.txt` not valid, only `2 > log.txt`. The question is why you get `Command line option syntax error. Type Command/ ? for Help."` message. Can you create a minimum reproducible example and attach it to the post?

Comment: And yet one moment: try `se.exe > log.txt`

Comment: Yes I tried, but that is not working too. I have attached the code in my original post. We are using Python 2.7.6 to run that. Please copy the code to make a .py file and then using iExpress create an exe to run it. Thanks for your continued support.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never used iExpress. Can you give me instructions how create an exe? And... why you don't use PyInstaller or py2exe or cx_freeze to make exe from python script? This is an easier way.

Comment: Actually, I was facing some issues creating exe using Pyinstaller and py2exe because there are some other files to include in the exe. I don't remember exactly why. Maybe I should try it again.
Using iExpress-Open it by searching "iexpress" from Windows start. Simply follow the steps & give some names where asked. Add the files you want to include in the exe. Main thing is when it asks to run a command after extracting the exe. It says "Install command". Put "cmd /c python.py"  without quotes. "Python" is your python script name. Post install, none. Towards the end, click both the check boxes.

Comment: It seems there is a way to do what you want - change `Install command`: instead `cmd /c python.py` using something like this: `cmd /c python python.py 2 > D:\log.txt`. Is it appropriate solution?

Comment: Thanks Northcat, that worked. :)
Just removed the additional "python" word from the command: cmd /c python.py 2 > D:\log.txt